# Displaying JSON information with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I validated my code and syntactically it all seems and looks correct to me. I am console logging my JSON file.

**Issue:**

I can't access the information from the file. I tried to run the function `productInfo` on its own. So, I suspect the issue is within there and it's not pulling in the information correctly. But I can't seem to find the exact issue.

Can anyone help with this?

**Javascript:**

```
// mapping jsonn file to varibale and starting the request to get information
let requestJson = 'https://brody413.github.io/JS-LAB-8/products.json';
let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('GET', requestJson);
myRequest.responseType = 'json';
myRequest.send();

// onload event so nothing happens till we have json 
myRequest.onload = function () {
    let jsonFile = myRequest.response;
    console.log(jsonFile);
    productInfo(jsonFile);
}

function productInfo(json) {
    let sectionElement = document.querySelector('section');

    let topDeals = json['topDeals'];
    for (let i = 0; i < topDeals; i++) {
        // creating elements to hold info
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        let p1 = document.createElement('p');
        let list = document.createElement('ul');
        let img = document.createElement('img');

        // giving each element the info
        h2.textContent = topDeals[i].name;
        h3.textContent = topDeals[i].price;
        p1.textContent = topDeals[i].description;

        let features = topFlavors[i].features;
        for (let x = 0; x < ingredients.length; x++) {
            let feature = document.createElement('li');
            feature.textContent = features[x];
            list.appendChild(feature);
        }

        div.appendChild(h2);
        div.appendChild(h3);
        div.appendChild(p1);
        div.appendChild(list);
        sectionElement.appendChild(div);

        console.log(div);
    }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "companyName": "I Scream Inc.",
    "headOffice": "Barrie, Ontario",
    "established": 2001,
    "active": true,
    "topDeals": [{
            "name": "Bacon Scented Mustache",
            "price": 4.07,
            "description": "Now you can smell bacon all day in peace.",
            "features": [
                "smells like bacon",
                "extra manly"
            ],
            "image": "bacon-scented-mustache.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dill pickle lip balm",
            "price": 11.95,
            "description": "Take your look to the next level with this amazing & dill-icious lip balm",
            "features": [
                "dill-icious",
                "beautiful green colour"
            ],
            "image": "dill-pickle-lip-balm.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dancing with cats",
            "price": 13.22,
            "description": "Learn intrepetive dance with your feline friend!",
            "features": [
                "all the latest dance moves",
                "truly bond with your cat through dance"
            ],
            "image": "dancing-with-cats.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MOD3 WEEK 8 - JSON</title>
    <script src='main.js' async></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>I Scream INC</h1>
        <p>Product Information is Below</p>
    </header>
    <main>
        <h3>PRODUCTS</h3>
        <section>
    

        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>Brody McColeman - WEEK 8 - SUMMER 2020</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, add your HTML code.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in your `for` statement and also you are not doing [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) properly.

1. For [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you need to use class or the id selector so it will check the exact class or id you are looking for
2. I have added and using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and *simplified* your code as well

Added comments as well to highlight stuff which needed a fix.

Run snippet below to see it working

```js
let requestJson = 'https://brody413.github.io/JS-LAB-8/products.json';
let myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('GET', requestJson);
myRequest.responseType = 'json';
myRequest.send();

// onload event so nothing happens till we have json 
myRequest.onload = function() {
  let jsonFile = myRequest.response;
  //console.log(jsonFile);
  productInfo(jsonFile);
}

function productInfo(json) {

  //All data will be appended here
  let sectionElement = document.querySelector('.section');

  let topDeals = json['topDeals'];

  //Foreach Loop for data
  topDeals.forEach(function(data) {
    // creating elements to hold info
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    let p1 = document.createElement('p');
    let list = document.createElement('ul');
    let img = document.createElement('img');

    // giving each element the info
    h2.textContent = data.name;
    h3.textContent = data.price;
    p1.textContent = data.description;

    //Foreach Loop for featues
    data.features.forEach(function(data) {
      let feature = document.createElement('li');
      feature.textContent = data
      list.appendChild(feature);
    })

    div.appendChild(h2);
    div.appendChild(h3);
    div.appendChild(p1);
    div.appendChild(list);
    
    //Append all the child element to parent .section
    sectionElement.appendChild(div);

  })
}
```

```html
<section class="section">

</section>
```